# Laravel: function returns value 1 all time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

I want to pass one value to the other function (createFields()) by Reference. But when I try to fetch that value in function, it prints 1 all the time.
Here is my code. I got correct value before passing it to another function. But when I pass it to another function, it change its value to 1.

**Note:** I am calling this function via Ajax.

```
public function example(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    // Requested request is in query string format, convert it into array
    parse_str($input['data'], $data);


    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // explode to get values after dash (-)
        $tmp              = explode('-', $key);

        $id = $this->getStatementIdByTitle('statements',
            $tmp[1]);

        $id2 = $id->id;

        // print correct value, i.e. 7
        // return json_encode($id2);

        $result = $this->createFields('table_name', $id2);

        // Print 1 all the time
        // return json_encode($result);
    }        
}

public function createFields($table, $id)
{
    // Print 1 all the time
    return json_encode($id);
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: you have 2 $id and your setting the value 2x, what does $id = $this->getStatementIdByTitle('statements',
            $tmp[1]); give?

Comment: @Didi Same value, 7. Which I want.

Comment: $result[] = $this->createFields('table_name', $id2); echo json_encode($result); what is the result